# Max of 8 UV maps on one Object?

Tags: texturing, uv

Working on a vending machine. Needing all the objects to be one object to port it in a mod for a video game. need multiple UV maps. In the UV Maps Tab in the Object Data Properties I go to add a new UV Map. At the moment I have 8 and will probably need around 11. When I press the Plus icon nothing happens and it wont let me add one. I can remove a layer and it lets me add one to replace but I can't go over 8. Am I missing something or is this a limitation? [image]

Comment: As I understand it you don't actually need multiple UVs, you just need multiple material slots. You can UV and texture each object separately and then join them and you'll have one object with multiple materials. The UVs of each part will overlap with the other parts, but that isn't a problem because they are assigned different materials. Unless you are using a game engine that has very specific limitations (unity and unreal work fine with multiple materials in same object).

Comment: Sadly its the infusion engine which is quite tricky.

Comment: Hi :). Yes this is a limitation of OpenGL, only 8 UV maps max.

Comment: That's not really an issue. You can offset similar islands which is prefered anyway, you can even have stacked UVs (per material as mentioned) and/or you can use UDIMs: https://docs.blender.org/manual/fr/2.82/modeling/meshes/editing/uv/workflows/udims.html

Comment: Like others here stated before, altough you might need everything to be one object, you don't have to use so many UV maps. I often use only one, and most of the time with overlapping faces. As long as those faces are assigned to different materials with different textures using the UV map that's no problem.